# ionic 2 Alert not working on webpage

Tags: ionic-framework, alert, nav, ionic2

I would like to raise an alert on Ionic2 when the device does not have a Camera.

When i launch :  ionic serve

then i try to display the message as follow :

```
 let alert = Alert.create({
                title: 'Camera not found',
                subTitle: 'It seems your camera is not working on your device',
                buttons: ['Ok']
            });
            this.nav.present(alert);
```

i have a javascript error

```
Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: rootNav.getActive is not a function
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: rootNav.getActive is not a function
    at Tab.NavController.present (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:46996:36)
    at SmartScan.takePicture (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:60864:23)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_SmartScan_0.handleEventInternal (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:14578:17), <anonymous>:185:36)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.handleEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:13892:25)
    at AppView.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:18772:46)
    at AppView.dispatchRenderEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:18766:22)
    at DefaultRenderView.dispatchRenderEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:33592:39)
    at eventDispatcher (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:33258:22)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:33329:40
```

[image]

Comment: Whether  this  code working  in  Mobile  builds..? .Please  elaborate

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that is not yet ready ...

investigating the code

```
        this.nav.present(alert);
```

it is passing here and returns :

```
if (rootNav['_tabs']) {
                // TODO: must have until this goes in
                // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5481
                void 0;
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

In alert.js:

```
import {Page, Alert, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({
templateUrl: 'build/pages/alert/alert.html'
})

export class AlertPage {
    static get parameters() {
        return [[NavController]];
    }
    constructor(nav) {
        this.nav = nav;
    }

    showAlert() {
        let alert = Alert.create({
            title: 'New Friend!',
            subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
            buttons: ['Ok']
        });
        this.nav.present(alert);

    }
}
```

In alert.html:

```
<button block dark (click)="showAlert()">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on ionic2 and was in the need to implement "PopUp" window in my existing application.
I try many for that by does not get my task accomplished, finally i did something like this-

1. pop-up.html
   `<button block dark (click)="showAlert()">Help Window</button>`
2. pop-up.ts

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { Alert, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';

   @Component({
     templateUrl: 'build/pages/pop-up/pop-up.html',
   })

   export class PopUpPage {
       static get parameters() {
         return [[NavController]];
       }
       constructor(private nav: NavController) {
         this.nav = nav;
       }

       showAlert() {
         let alert = Alert.create({
           title: 'Help Window!',
           subTitle: 'Mindfulness is here for you and your soul. We are intended to stablish your connection to All Mighty.',
           buttons: ['Cancle']
         });
         this.nav.present(alert);
       }
   }
   ```

And that work fine for me.

[image]

Hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

with this structure of folder and files

[image]

In:

> home.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Ionic 2 Notifications</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <button block dark (click)="showAlert()">Alert</button>
</ion-content>
```

In:

> home.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {NavController, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

  showAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Friend!',
      subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }

}
```

I got this information from the documentation site:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#action-sheets